# kubernetes 1.27.4 init fails for offline environment

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to install kubernetes to my offline environment. I have downloaded all the related packages (rpms for docer/kubernetes , containers for k8s etc) and I loaded them. Below is the list of my docker images.

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nginx/nginx-ingress                       latest    9c101cf3a6a1   2 days ago      304MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.27.4   e7972205b661   11 days ago     121MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.27.4   6848d7eda034   11 days ago     71.1MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.27.4   98ef2570f3cd   11 days ago     58.4MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.27.4   f466468864b7   11 days ago     113MB
calico/kube-controllers                   v3.26.1   1919f2787fa7   6 weeks ago     75.1MB
calico/cni                                v3.26.1   9dee260ef7f5   6 weeks ago     210MB
calico/node                               v3.26.1   8065b798a4d6   6 weeks ago     246MB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.10.1   ead0a4a53df8   5 months ago    53.6MB
registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.7-0   86b6af7dd652   6 months ago    296MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9       e6f181688397   9 months ago    744kB
```

When I try to run `kubeadm init` command to start related services and run k8s pods, I'm getting error as below.

```
[root@eepk8smaster01 ~]# kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=1.27.4 --pod-network-cidr=<IP_ADDRESS>/<MASK> --apiserver-advertise-address=<IP Address> --v=5
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
I0731 10:59:59.519458  144562 checks.go:828] **using image pull policy: IfNotPresent**
I0731 10:59:59.541504  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4
I0731 10:59:59.752147  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.27.4
I0731 10:59:59.894380  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.27.4
I0731 11:00:00.039525  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.27.4
W0731 11:00:00.191131  144562 checks.go:835] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm. It is recommended that using "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
I0731 11:00:00.213108  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9
I0731 11:00:00.353651  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.7-0
I0731 11:00:00.505605  144562 checks.go:854] pulling: registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.10.1
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR ImagePull]: **failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4**: output: E0731 10:59:59.727411  144620 remote_image.go:171] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.27.4\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60605->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4"
time="2023-07-31T10:59:59+03:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.27.4\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60605->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
```

I'm getting this error for all the pods (apiserver,proxy,scheduler,etcd,coredns,pause).
Does kubernetes support offline installation for kubernetes 1.27.4? I found some writings about the related topic for older version kubernetes but there is no documentation for 1.27.4.

**EDIT 1**
I passed the *failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4* step by deploying a localhost docker registry and pushed my images with tagging them. (The name should be same as the output of the error: ***kube-apiserver:v1.27.4***). After that it tries to create manifest files, etc. When it comes to ***etcd***, it throws timeout error.

```
 [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
I0731 14:20:20.276614  196796 local.go:65] [etcd] wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd member to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
I0731 14:20:20.276628  196796 waitcontrolplane.go:83] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
```

**EDIT 2:**
I figured out from the `journalctl -xeu kubelet` that `kubeadm init` tries to pull the *pause3.6* image from the internet. The strange
thing about this is, as shown below kubernetes requires *pause3.9*

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubeadm config images list
W0801 13:23:26.353378  140838 version.go:104] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": dial tcp: lookup dl.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:32782->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
W0801 13:23:26.353425  140838 version.go:105] falling back to the local client version: v1.27.4
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.4
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.27.4
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.27.4
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.27.4
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9
registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.7-0
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.10.1
```

As it is stated from the command, I downloaded *pause3.9* image, tagged it and pushed it to my local registry.

```
[dockeruser@k8smaster ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nginx/nginx-ingress                       latest    9c101cf3a6a1   3 days ago      304MB
localhost:5000/kube-apiserver             v1.27.4   e7972205b661   12 days ago     121MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.27.4   e7972205b661   12 days ago     121MB
localhost:5000/kube-controller-manager    v1.27.4   f466468864b7   12 days ago     113MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.27.4   f466468864b7   12 days ago     113MB
localhost:5000/kube-scheduler             v1.27.4   98ef2570f3cd   12 days ago     58.4MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.27.4   98ef2570f3cd   12 days ago     58.4MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.27.4   6848d7eda034   12 days ago     71.1MB
localhost:5000/kube-proxy                 v1.27.4   6848d7eda034   12 days ago     71.1MB
calico/kube-controllers                   v3.26.1   1919f2787fa7   6 weeks ago     75.1MB
calico/cni                                v3.26.1   9dee260ef7f5   6 weeks ago     210MB
calico/node                               v3.26.1   8065b798a4d6   6 weeks ago     246MB
registry                                  latest    4bb5ea59f8e0   6 weeks ago     24MB
localhost:5000/coredns                    v1.10.1   ead0a4a53df8   5 months ago    53.6MB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.10.1   ead0a4a53df8   5 months ago    53.6MB
localhost:5000/etcd                       3.5.7-0   86b6af7dd652   6 months ago    296MB
registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.7-0   86b6af7dd652   6 months ago    296MB
localhost:5000/pause                      3.9       e6f181688397   9 months ago    744kB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9       e6f181688397   9 months ago    744kB
```

After I start `kubeadm init` the strange thing is that it gives output as below. It says that it will be using 3.6 but in the next line it pulls *pause3.9* image.

```
W0801 13:10:52.299341  140181 checks.go:835] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm. It is recommended that using "localhost:5000/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
I0801 13:10:52.320163  140181 checks.go:846] image exists: localhost:5000/pause:3.9
```

Also the `journalctl -xeu` command log is below. It is trying to pull *pause3.6*

```
Aug 01 12:13:45 k8smaster kubelet[137232]: E0801 12:13:45.492979  137232 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:72] "Failed to create sandbox for pod" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:55799->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-k8smaster"
```

After reading this I pulled *pause3.6* image and pushed it to my local registry. (I put only the relevant output).

REPOSITORY                                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
localhost:5000/pause                      3.9       e6f181688397   9 months ago    744kB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9       e6f181688397   9 months ago    744kB
localhost:5000/pause                      3.6       6270bb605e12   23 months ago   683kB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.6       6270bb605e12   23 months ago   683kB

Again I run `kubeadm init` command but it failed again despite the fact that *pause3.6* and *pause3.9* images are in my local registry. The journalctl log is below. Again it tries to pull the pause3.6 image from internet

```
Aug 01 13:52:43 k8smaster kubelet[137389]: E0801 13:52:43.429009  137389 kuberuntime_manager.go:1122] "CreatePodSandbox for pod failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33123->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" pod="kube-system/etcd-k8smaster"
```

How can I prevent kubeadm to pull the image from registry.k8s.io in this situation?
**NOTE**: I tried to push only the *pause3.6* image and `kubeadm init` command again failed because it was looking for *pause3.9*

Comment: Kindly check CRI which has been used by running "kubeadm config print init-defaults".   From init input which has been provided its still pulling images from the google registry.   once kubeadm config images pull is run.  when init command is executed you should see following output.

Comment: I0731 16:21:13.573016  844022 checks.go:828] using image pull policy: IfNotPresent
I0731 16:21:13.601375  844022 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.2
I0731 16:21:13.629182  844022 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.27.2
I0731 16:21:13.654809  844022 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.27.2
I0731 16:21:13.682667  844022 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.27.2

Comment: @G.Baysec, I have edited my answer for the issues you are encountering in pulling the image. Can you please try this and let me know if the issue still persists. I am happy to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

It is a clear error, It is looking for **kube-apiserver:v1.27.4** which is a docker image and you can't pull the image without the internet. Now you have two options one is to connect with the network and run the setup and then go offline. (**I never worked on offline k8s I am just replying to you with logic.**)
The other option is to visit the [K8s-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)  and download the kube-api server yaml file then deploy it manually. Once this file is up you should go through this init.

Comment: Isn't there a way for kubeadm init to look at the local docker images? I saw documentation for older versions of kubernetes which use the same method as mine. When they use 'kubeadm init', k8s pull the images from local docker images. The methods are not working for me. I can't go online than offline and k8s-hard-way method has older versions.

Comment: How come kube-apiserver is running on docker? Can you please conform if you have pulled kube-API in your local Docker with the Docker pull command?  Can you please shear the documentation you are following? It seems very interesting.  You can download the kube-api-server binary and install it manually. Or if you are using kube-admin then I think it has to be online to fetch it from the docker hub.

Comment: Hello. I download the kube-API and other containers with docker pull command. I save them to .tar files and copy them to my offline environment. I followed the "Install Docker & setup Kubernetes cluster offline " post. It was a post from linkedin. I also double check something from other posts but they were all the same.

Answer (score 0):

By default, kubeadm pulls the required images from a container registry such as docker hub or private registry. However you can use a **local docker image repository** for an offline environment.

To use local images, you need to save them as tar files and copy them to an offline environment where you are using kubeadm init. Load the image tar files into docker on the offline machine using docker load command and start the kubeadm init process which will use the locally available docker images instead of pulling them from a remote registry.

The `[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed` error is an indication that the kubelet and/or kube-apiserver are failing to start. You need to look at the logs of kubelet and apiserver. If you run kubelet using systemd, then you could use the following method to see kubelet's logs:

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

Please note that the specific images you need may vary depending on the kubernetes version and the components you choose to install. Make sure to obtain the correct images for the kubernetes version 1.27.4 from a reliable source.

You can refer to [Troubleshooting Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#kubeadm-blocks-waiting-for-control-plane-during-installation) documentation for further information.

---

**EDIT :**

If you have already pushed the correct pause3.6 image and still encountering the issue, it is possible that the kubeadm configuration is set to use a different version of the pause image. For this, open the kubeadm.conf file and in imageRepository field update the value to point to your local image repository where the pause3.6 image is stored and reinitialize kubernetes.

Verify the image tag is pause3.6 and ensure the image is accessible in local repository.

Comment: Hello, I reviewed the journalctl logs for kubelet and I found an interesting thing. Despite the fact that I'm using '--image-repository localhost:5000' switch, kubeadm init tries to pull pause3.6 from internet. The problem here is that, the 'kubeadm config images list' states that I needed 'pause3.9'.  Despite that I downloaded 'pause3.6' image from online, reset my registry and pushed only the 'pause3.6' to registry. After that, in 'kubeadm init' output, it said 'image exists: localhost:50000/pause3.9'. I didn't even push 3.9 and I also delete the registry beforehand.